# Citing with biblatex style=verbose and \footcite: disable links but keep them for normal hyperlinks

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I don't like the way [Biblatex][1] works, when used with `style=verbose` and `\footcite`.

It creates citations in footer (correct), when using book more than once, the next ones are shortened (correct), but next links leads to first citation in the footnote :(. I'd like to be linked either in bibliography or not at all.

Maybe it can be done somehow with `NoHyper`, but I have no idea how.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[pdfborder=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{foo2018,
    title = "Filosofie hodnot: problémy lidské existence, poznání a hodnocení",
    author = "Soňa Dorotíková",
    isbn = "80-86039-79-X",
    year = "1998",
    publisher = "Pedagogická fakulta Univerzity Karlovy"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Full description, not clickable:
\footcite[1]{foo2018}

Short description, but link to previous footcite, which I don't want:
\footcite[164]{foo2018}.

This should be clickable
\url{http://kernel.org}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, `verbose` is set up not to need a bibliography, thus no link to one, which may be absent. You can pass the option `hyperref=false` to `biblatex`, that will remove these links between footnotes and allow `hyperref` to do the usual job with a regular url. I'm not sure, though, if a url within a reference will remain linked.

Comment: Thanks a lot, passing the option `hyperref=false` to biblatex was a solution. Simple, nice, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop the `verbose` citation styles from creating links to footnotes with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhypertarget}{#1}
```

and with

```
\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperlink}{bibhyperref}
```

you link short citations to the bibliography instead.

---

With

```
\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhypertarget}{bibhyperref}
```

instead of `\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhypertarget}{#1}` you also link the full citation to the bibliography.

Comment: Also very nice, thanks! Probably prefer `\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhypertarget}{#1}`.

Comment: Is it possible to disable links selectively either per citation or for every use of a particular citation command? I use e.g. `\fullcite{}` in cases where I'm not including something in the bibliography, but then Biblatex makes hyperlinks to No Man's Land (page 1).

Comment: @cfr Sure, you can include the code above in a redefinition of the `\footcite` command for example.

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex`'s `verbose` style is set up not to need a bibliography, as all the bibliographical information is given in full in the first citation. Thus, links are made to the first citation and not to the bibliography, which may be absent.

If you don't want this link between citation/footnotes, you can use the option `hyperref=false` which will remove them. And will not hinder `hyperref` itself from doing it's usual job with a proper url.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{foo2018,
    title = "Filosofie hodnot: problémy lidské existence, poznání a hodnocení",
    author = "Soňa Dorotíková",
    isbn = "80-86039-79-X",
    year = "1998",
    publisher = "Pedagogická fakulta Univerzity Karlovy",
}

@online{bar2017,
  author = {Baz},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2017},
  url = {http://kernel.org},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose,backend=biber,hyperref=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Full description, not clickable:
\footcite[1]{foo2018}

Short description, but link to previous footcite, which I don't want:
\footcite[164]{foo2018}.

\footcite{bar2017}.

This should be clickable
\url{http://kernel.org}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]